# XNA 3D collision detection for two triangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d, xna, collision-detection

I have been trying to make collisions work for about 50 hours now. First I tried to write my own detection but didn't come even close to making it work. Then I tried to Implement [Moller's fast triangle triangle intersection test](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Tomas_Akenine-Moller/pubs/tritri.pdf) by understanding the math in the paper, but I failed. Then I tried just to convert the C code from the link in the paper to c# (The link is dead but i have found the supposedly original code [here](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Tomas_Akenine-Moller/code/opttritri.txt)) but it didn't work once again. After some more searching I have found that code converted to C# for unity [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/861719/a-fast-triangle-triangle-intersection-algorithm-fo.html). With a bit of tweaking I changed it to XNA but it still doesn't work.

This it the tweaked code from the last link:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// Tri/Tri intersection. Implementation of Tomas Moller, 1997.
/// See article "A Fast Triangle-Triangle Intersection Test", Journal of Graphics Tools, 2(2), 1997.
/// </summary>
public static class TriTriOverlap
{
    private static void Sort(Vector2 v)
    {
        if (v.X > v.Y)
        {
            float c;
            c = v.X;
            v.X = v.Y;
            v.Y = c;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This edge to edge test is based on Franlin Antonio's gem: "Faster Line Segment Intersection", in Graphics Gems III, pp. 199-202 
    /// </summary>
    private static bool EdgeEdgeTest(Vector3 v0, Vector3 v1, Vector3 u0, Vector3 u1, int i0, int i1)
    {
        float Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, e, d, f;
        Ax = GetComponentFromIndex(v1, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i0);
        Ay = GetComponentFromIndex(v1, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i1);
        Bx = GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i0);
        By = GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i1);
        Cx = GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i0);
        Cy = GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i1);
        f = Ay * Bx - Ax * By;
        d = By * Cx - Bx * Cy;
        if ((f > 0 && d >= 0 && d <= f) || (f < 0 && d <= 0 && d >= f))
        {
            e = Ax * Cy - Ay * Cx;
            if (f > 0)
            {
                if (e >= 0 && e <= f) { return true; }
            }
            else
            {
                if (e <= 0 && e >= f) { return true; }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool EdgeAgainstTriEdges(Vector3 v0, Vector3 v1, Vector3 u0, Vector3 u1, Vector3 u2, short i0, short i1)
    {
        // test edge u0,u1 against v0,v1
        if (EdgeEdgeTest(v0, v1, u0, u1, i0, i1)) { return true; }

        // test edge u1,u2 against v0,v1 
        if (EdgeEdgeTest(v0, v1, u1, u2, i0, i1)) { return true; }

        // test edge u2,u1 against v0,v1 
        if (EdgeEdgeTest(v0, v1, u2, u0, i0, i1)) { return true; }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool PointInTri(Vector3 v0, Vector3 u0, Vector3 u1, Vector3 u2, short i0, short i1)
    {
        float a, b, c, d0, d1, d2;

        // is T1 completly inside T2?
        // check if v0 is inside tri(u0,u1,u2)
        a = GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i1);
        b = -(GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i0));
        c = -a * GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i0) - b * GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i1);
        d0 = a * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i0) + b * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i1) + c;

        a = GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i1);
        b = -(GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i0));
        c = -a * GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i0) - b * GetComponentFromIndex(u1, i1);
        d1 = a * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i0) + b * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i1) + c;

        a = GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i1) - GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i1);
        b = -(GetComponentFromIndex(u0, i0) - GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i0));
        c = -a * GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i0) - b * GetComponentFromIndex(u2, i1);
        d2 = a * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i0) + b * GetComponentFromIndex(v0, i1) + c;

        if (d0 * d1 > 0.0f)
        {
            if (d0 * d2 > 0.0f) { return true; }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static bool TriTriCoplanar(Vector3 N, Vector3 v0, Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, Vector3 u0, Vector3 u1, Vector3 u2)
    {
        float[] A = new float[3];
        short i0, i1;

        // first project onto an axis-aligned plane, that maximizes the area
        // of the triangles, compute indices: i0,i1. 
        A[0] = Math.Abs(N.X);
        A[1] = Math.Abs(N.Y);
        A[2] = Math.Abs(N.Z);
        if (A[0] > A[1])
        {
            if (A[0] > A[2])
            {
                // A[0] is greatest
                i0 = 1;
                i1 = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                // A[2] is greatest
                i0 = 0;
                i1 = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (A[2] > A[1])
            {
                // A[2] is greatest 
                i0 = 0;
                i1 = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // A[1] is greatest 
                i0 = 0;
                i1 = 2;
            }
        }

        // test all edges of triangle 1 against the edges of triangle 2 
        if (EdgeAgainstTriEdges(v0, v1, u0, u1, u2, i0, i1)) { return true; }
        if (EdgeAgainstTriEdges(v1, v2, u0, u1, u2, i0, i1)) { return true; }
        if (EdgeAgainstTriEdges(v2, v0, u0, u1, u2, i0, i1)) { return true; }

        // finally, test if tri1 is totally contained in tri2 or vice versa 
        if (PointInTri(v0, u0, u1, u2, i0, i1)) { return true; }
        if (PointInTri(u0, v0, v1, v2, i0, i1)) { return true; }

        return false;
    }



    private static bool ComputeIntervals(float VV0, float VV1, float VV2,
                              float D0, float D1, float D2, float D0D1, float D0D2,
                              ref float A, ref float B, ref float C, ref float X0, ref float X1)
    {
        if (D0D1 > 0.0f)
        {
            // here we know that D0D2<=0.0 
            // that is D0, D1 are on the same side, D2 on the other or on the plane 
            A = VV2; B = (VV0 - VV2) * D2; C = (VV1 - VV2) * D2; X0 = D2 - D0; X1 = D2 - D1;
        }
        else if (D0D2 > 0.0f)
        {
            // here we know that d0d1<=0.0 
            A = VV1; B = (VV0 - VV1) * D1; C = (VV2 - VV1) * D1; X0 = D1 - D0; X1 = D1 - D2;
        }
        else if (D1 * D2 > 0.0f || D0 != 0.0f)
        {
            // here we know that d0d1<=0.0 or that D0!=0.0 
            A = VV0; B = (VV1 - VV0) * D0; C = (VV2 - VV0) * D0; X0 = D0 - D1; X1 = D0 - D2;
        }
        else if (D1 != 0.0f)
        {
            A = VV1; B = (VV0 - VV1) * D1; C = (VV2 - VV1) * D1; X0 = D1 - D0; X1 = D1 - D2;
        }
        else if (D2 != 0.0f)
        {
            A = VV2; B = (VV0 - VV2) * D2; C = (VV1 - VV2) * D2; X0 = D2 - D0; X1 = D2 - D1;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the triangle V(v0, v1, v2) intersects the triangle U(u0, u1, u2).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="v0">Vertex 0 of V</param>
    /// <param name="v1">Vertex 1 of V</param>
    /// <param name="v2">Vertex 2 of V</param>
    /// <param name="u0">Vertex 0 of U</param>
    /// <param name="u1">Vertex 1 of U</param>
    /// <param name="u2">Vertex 2 of U</param>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if V intersects U, otherwise <c>false</c></returns>
    public static bool TriTriIntersect(Vector3 v0, Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, Vector3 u0, Vector3 u1, Vector3 u2)
    {
        Vector3 e1, e2;
        Vector3 n1, n2;
        Vector3 dd;
        Vector2 isect1 = Vector2.Zero, isect2 = Vector2.Zero;

        float du0, du1, du2, dv0, dv1, dv2, d1, d2;
        float du0du1, du0du2, dv0dv1, dv0dv2;
        float vp0, vp1, vp2;
        float up0, up1, up2;
        float bb, cc, max;

        short index;

        // compute plane equation of triangle(v0,v1,v2) 
        e1 = v1 - v0;
        e2 = v2 - v0;
        n1 = Vector3.Cross(e1, e2);
        d1 = -Vector3.Dot(n1, v0);
        // plane equation 1: N1.X+d1=0 */

        // put u0,u1,u2 into plane equation 1 to compute signed distances to the plane
        du0 = Vector3.Dot(n1, u0) + d1;
        du1 = Vector3.Dot(n1, u1) + d1;
        du2 = Vector3.Dot(n1, u2) + d1;

        // coplanarity robustness check 
        if (Math.Abs(du0) < float.Epsilon) { du0 = 0.0f; }
        if (Math.Abs(du1) < float.Epsilon) { du1 = 0.0f; }
        if (Math.Abs(du2) < float.Epsilon) { du2 = 0.0f; }

        du0du1 = du0 * du1;
        du0du2 = du0 * du2;

        // same sign on all of them + not equal 0 ? 
        if (du0du1 > 0.0f && du0du2 > 0.0f)
        {
            // no intersection occurs
            return false;
        }

        // compute plane of triangle (u0,u1,u2)
        e1 = u1 - u0;
        e2 = u2 - u0;
        n2 = Vector3.Cross(e1, e2);
        d2 = -Vector3.Dot(n2, u0);

        // plane equation 2: N2.X+d2=0 
        // put v0,v1,v2 into plane equation 2
        dv0 = Vector3.Dot(n2, v0) + d2;
        dv1 = Vector3.Dot(n2, v1) + d2;
        dv2 = Vector3.Dot(n2, v2) + d2;

        if (Math.Abs(dv0) < float.Epsilon) { dv0 = 0.0f; }
        if (Math.Abs(dv1) < float.Epsilon) { dv1 = 0.0f; }
        if (Math.Abs(dv2) < float.Epsilon) { dv2 = 0.0f; }


        dv0dv1 = dv0 * dv1;
        dv0dv2 = dv0 * dv2;

        // same sign on all of them + not equal 0 ? 
        if (dv0dv1 > 0.0f && dv0dv2 > 0.0f)
        {
            // no intersection occurs
            return false;
        }

        // compute direction of intersection line 
        dd = Vector3.Cross(n1, n2);

        // compute and index to the largest component of D 
        max = Math.Abs(dd.X);
        index = 0;
        bb = Math.Abs(dd.Y);
        cc = Math.Abs(dd.Z);
        if (bb > max) { max = bb; index = 1; }
        if (cc > max) { max = cc; index = 2; }

        // this is the simplified projection onto L
        vp0 = GetComponentFromIndex(v0, index);
        vp1 = GetComponentFromIndex(v1, index);
        vp2 = GetComponentFromIndex(v2, index);

        up0 = GetComponentFromIndex(u0, index);
        up1 = GetComponentFromIndex(u1, index);
        up2 = GetComponentFromIndex(u2, index);

        // compute interval for triangle 1 
        float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, x0 = 0, x1 = 0;
        if (ComputeIntervals(vp0, vp1, vp2, dv0, dv1, dv2, dv0dv1, dv0dv2, ref a, ref b, ref c, ref x0, ref x1))
        {
            return TriTriCoplanar(n1, v0, v1, v2, u0, u1, u2);
        }

        // compute interval for triangle 2 
        float d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, y0 = 0, y1 = 0;
        if (ComputeIntervals(up0, up1, up2, du0, du1, du2, du0du1, du0du2, ref d, ref e, ref f, ref y0, ref y1))
        {
            return TriTriCoplanar(n1, v0, v1, v2, u0, u1, u2);
        }

        float xx, yy, xxyy, tmp;
        xx = x0 * x1;
        yy = y0 * y1;
        xxyy = xx * yy;

        tmp = a * xxyy;
        isect1.X = tmp + b * x1 * yy;
        isect1.Y = tmp + c * x0 * yy;

        tmp = d * xxyy;
        isect2.X = tmp + e * xx * y1;
        isect2.Y = tmp + f * xx * y0;

        Sort(isect1);
        Sort(isect2);

        return !(isect1.Y < isect2.X || isect2.Y < isect1.X);
    }

    private static float GetComponentFromIndex(Vector3 v, int c)
    {
        if (c == 0) return v.X;
        if (c == 1) return v.Y;
        if (c == 2) return v.Z;
        else return float.PositiveInfinity;
    }
}
```

Please help me get it to work.

EDIT:
My new code using separating axes theorem (SAT). Polygon class represents triangles.

```
private static bool SATColl(Polygon T1, Polygon T2)
{
    Vector3 A0 = GetPointVectors(T1.Vertices[0].Position);
    Vector3 A1 = GetPointVectors(T1.Vertices[1].Position);
    Vector3 A2 = GetPointVectors(T1.Vertices[2].Position);

    Vector3 E0 = A1 - A0;
    Vector3 E1 = A2 - A0;
    Vector3 E2 = E1 - E0;

    Vector3 N = Vector3.Cross(E0, E1);


    Vector3 B0 = GetPointVectors(T2.Vertices[0].Position);
    Vector3 B1 = GetPointVectors(T2.Vertices[1].Position);
    Vector3 B2 = GetPointVectors(T2.Vertices[2].Position);

    Vector3 F0 = B1 - B0;
    Vector3 F1 = B2 - B0;
    Vector3 F2 = F1 - F0;

    Vector3 M = Vector3.Cross(F0, F1);

    Vector3 D = Vector3.Cross(N, M);
    D.Normalize();

    Vector2 pA0 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(A0, D / D.Length()) * D);
    Vector2 pA1 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(A1, D / D.Length()) * D);
    Vector2 pA2 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(A2, D / D.Length()) * D);
    Vector2 pB0 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(B0, D / D.Length()) * D);
    Vector2 pB1 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(B1, D / D.Length()) * D);
    Vector2 pB2 = Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3.Dot(B2, D / D.Length()) * D);

    if (IsInTriangle(pA0, pB0, pB1, pB2) || IsInTriangle(pA1, pB0, pB1, pB2) || IsInTriangle(pA2, pB0, pB1, pB2))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static Vector2 Vec3XYToVec2(Vector3 v)
{
    if (v.Z != 0)
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    return new Vector2(v.X, v.Y);
}
private static bool IsInTriangle(Vector2 pt, Vector2 tPt0, Vector2 tPt1, Vector2 tPt2)
{
    bool b1 = DistanceFromLine(pt, tPt0, tPt1) <= 0.0f;
    bool b2 = DistanceFromLine(pt, tPt1, tPt2) <= 0.0f;
    bool b3 = DistanceFromLine(pt, tPt2, tPt0) <= 0.0f;

    return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3));
}
private static float DistanceFromLine(Vector2 pt, Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return (b.X - a.X) * (pt.Y - a.Y) - (b.Y - a.Y) * (pt.X - a.X);
}
```

Comment: Recommendation, use an implementation of separating axes theorem (SAT), is a lot faster and is easier to program

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Method `TriTriIntersect` doesn't return bool correctly.

Comment: @Gusman I am trying to implement SAT now from [this](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DynamicCollisionDetection.pdf) site. Im lost on page 23 on last paragraph on the page. What is L supposed to be? Is it N, M, or Ei × Fj?? and if there are defined p0, p1, p2 and q0, q1, q2 what are supposed to be just p and q on page 25 under stationary?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html it's for 2D but the theorem is the same, the only difference is the axes, in 3D you have one axis per face, and it is its normal

Comment: @Gusman If I understand correctly I have to project all the points to a plane which is perpendicular to the both triangle normals. How can i project them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection look at the Vector part

Comment: @Gusman What calculation is not working correctly in the edit?

Comment: @Timiimit What do you mean?

Comment: @Gusman I edited the original post and what I came up with isn't working.

Comment: Does `Vector3.Dot(A0, D / D.Length()) * D` get point projected on a plane, where `A0` is projected point and `D` is plane's normal?